# I can't get the parameter in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a custom route for my controller but when i pass the parameter in the url i can't get the variable in the controller class the ouput is empty.

The route

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "Employee", "Employee/{name}", new
           {controller = "Employee", action = "Search", name = UrlParameter.Optional}
);
```

Class EmployeeController

```
    public ActionResult Search(string name)
    {
        var input = Server.HtmlEncode(name);
        return Content(input);
    }
```

Comment: Show us how you're calling this method.

Comment: Works fine when calling `rootURL/Employee/george` (outputs `"george"`)

Comment: can you provide all routes mentioned in your file?

Comment: here is my table http://paste.ofcode.org/qmNFcdFrTyg3rEfYuZfa8Y, y try this url http://localhost:54484/Employee/MyName but doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your custom route needs to come *before* the default one so it matches first:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Employee",
    url: "Employee/{name}", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Employee", action = "Search", name = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Since you defined the route URL to `"Employee/{name}"`, and having a `public ActionResult Search(string name)` action signature in `EmployeeController`, you should be able to match using the following formats:

- `/Employee/George`
- `/Employee?name=George`

Both will return `"George"`.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question, you can click on the check mark beside the answer to mark it as accepted.